# Sharepoint webpart and overiding the css style

Tags: css, sharepoint, web-parts

Have a look at this picture

[alt text http://www.abbeylegal.com/downloads/2009-04-01/web%20part%20top%20line.jpg](http://www.abbeylegal.com/downloads/2009-04-01/web%20part%20top%20line.jpg)

Does anyone know what css style is used for the line/border highlighted in red? I'm trying to over ride it in my custom style sheet but I’m not having any luck, so far I’ve tried overiding these different styles...

.ms-viewheadertr 
.ms-vh2  
.ms-vb 
.ms-vb2 
.ms-unselectedtitle 
.ms-summarystandardbody

which is changing the display but not the border, it's enough to make you go mad!

Update:

*.ms-WPHeader* is indeed one of the css classes, however if you set the border-style to none there is still a line that appears; just a little thinner. I can use *.ms-viewheadertr* to completely remove the header but just can't seem remove this one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work intensively on customising sharepoint UI. So i know for sure that the class you should be looking at is the following:

```
*.ms-vh,.ms-vh2,.ms-vh-icon,.ms-vh2-nofilter,.ms-vh2-nofilter-icon,.ms-viewheadertr .ms-vh-group,.ms-vh2-nograd,.ms-vh3-nograd,.ms-vh2-nograd-icon,.ms-ph,.ms-pickerresultheadertr{
background-image:url("/_layouts/images/viewheadergrad.gif");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
padding-top:1px;
padding-bottom:0px;
background-color:#f2f2f2;
}*
```

You should remove the image reference in the background-image property like so:

```
*background-image:url("");*
```

That will remove the dark greyish line on top.

Happy Customising!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use firefox & the firebug addon to work out which classes to override?

Are you using !importance to override the css classes?

Comment: Hi, I am using both, which has got me so far with the styles i've listed but not far enough, thanks for the !importance tip, i'll try that now.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome seems to suggest that it's the iframe (id `Filterlframe1`) that's the culprit:

```
border-bottom-style: inset;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
```

Clarification: the Sharepoint list view uses an iframe for the menu bar at the top - that's where the border is being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after playing in the IE8 dev toolbar, I came up with:

```
<tr class="ms-WPHeader">
```

CSS props:

```
border-bottom:#4e7cb7 1px solid;
border-collapse:collapse;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Heather Solomom's SharePoint CSS reference at http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm.

Browsing through the webpart specific section at http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm#WebParts, it looks like this might be ms-WPBorder perhaps?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed each of the responses and none of them was successful. The key is the color of the line "#4E7CB7". I then searched the root CSS files on the server and at line 2683 of the CORE.css I changed the

```
.ms-WPHeader TD {
    border-bottom:1px solid #4e7cb7;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

to

```
.ms-WPHeader TD {
    border-bottom:0px solid #4e7cb7;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```